# caching a value common to two jvms

Tags: java, ehcache, data-sharing

I am storing a key value property using ehcache. This is used in a java program X. Now I am using another java program Y, where I want to use the same key value pair. I will read and may update the key value pair from any one of the two java programs X or Y. Both X, Y run at the same time.

Comment: If you use [memcached](http://memcached.org/) I think it'll be distributed, otherwise the two JVM instances do not directly share memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two applications, you have two jvm and you have to use replication between the two ehcaches.

If you decide to apply replication to the ehcaches, here is a complete guide about it

http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.9.0/pdf/Ehcache_Replication_Guide.pdf

BUT

I give you another solution, why not use a very fast, key value and big data database like REDIS.

http://redis.io/

It will be properly integrated with spring data into yours projects like a normal database  and you will be able read and write very fast.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-redis/

try it!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use distributed cache or ehcache replication. To start thinking what to choose you could read [this](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.6/get-started/about-distributed-cache). I am personaly prefer [distributed cache](http://terracotta.org/downloads/open-source/catalog), because it more flexible and easer to use. You just need to setup tsa server and configure caches to use server.